# Kids. Humorous SF/ fantasy book. A boy has fireworks spring from his head every time he gets his hair cut

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

It was a thin paperback kids book for maybe 8-10 year olds. I read it about 1979 in the UK.

The boy protagonist may have been called Danny. It is possibly a Danny Dunn book, I read some others at the time.

Something happened to him so that forever afterwards fireworks sprang from his hair whenever it was cut.

His parent decided the best thing to do was to only cut his hair once a year, and invite all his friends to the event, so they could enjoy the fireworks.

Nobody in the book worried that explosions so close to his eyes might blind him.